# Does overwriting a file consumes extra space?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, storage-spaces, overwrite, teracopy

I have 1gb available space in my HDD which is composed of mainly movies and I want to overwrite files with same names and file size. The file that I want to replace is a 2gb movie and I want to replace it with the exact same file but with subtitles because I copy the movie from my HDD to my desktop and put subtitles on it and now I want to replace the movie with no subtitle with it. So my question is does overwriting a file consumes extra space?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possibilities:

1. Copy the new file under a temporary name. If copy has gone without errors delete original file and rename the new file to the original name. This takes obviously extra space for the whole copy, but it is the safe thing to do. If something goes wrong during the copy you still have the original file in place.
2. Simply delete the original file first, then write the new file. Doesn't take extra space.
3. Write the new content over the existing file. This incurs (depending on filesystem) a small amount (typically a few kilobytes) of overhead in disk-space, which is neglectable.

Which method is used is determined by the copy-software. Some have options to control the behavior.
Variant 2 is almost always the default as it is the easiest thing to do for the copy-software.
If the software doesn't specify how it is doing it and you can't select a method in that software, it is easy to test whether it uses method 1: Just copy a large file twice and check the free diskspace while the second copy is being made. If it drops it is 1. If it doesn't drop (or only a very little bit) it is 2 or 3.
You can't really tell if it is 2 or 3 because disk-space will always fluctuate a little bit (internal housekeeping by the OS, other programs running) when the computer is in use.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the tips. So from what I understand overwriting is simply windows copying the new file in deleting the old file which obviously use extra space in HDD during the process. Is that right?

Comment: Normally you would be using up to 4 GB while copying, which at the end would be reduced to 2 GB, freeing the space taken by the old file.

Comment: I see but is it still the same case if I use teracopy and choose the option "overwrite old files"?

Comment: @JohnfritzAntipuesto I wouldn't know. I have never used Teracopy. With that setting it probably uses variant 2 or 3, but how it goes about it exactly can only be answered by the authors of that software.